# Can 弗 Mean Dollar In Chinese?

Tags: meaning

弗 means dollar (as in USD, $) in both Korean and Japanese.

Korean

> 불
>
> [弗] a dollar

Japnese

> ドル
>
> noun
>
> 1. dollar (from Dutch, orig. an abbr. of ドルラル; also written as 弗) (see also: ドルラル)

Grand Ricci says that 弗 fú is:

> 6 (Écon. – Fin.) Car. empl. pr le symbole $ : dollar.

the pronunciation of the dollar symbol in Chinese.

I haven't seen any other acknowledgement of 弗 fú having anything to do with US Dollars in any other dictionaries.

- Can 弗 Mean Dollar In Chinese?

Comment: 弗 in Canto is pronounced fat1 the same as: 窟 which means 块....wonder if there's a connection there

Comment: 窟 (hole/cave/den) does not mean 块/塊 (piece/lump/dollar) in any way to me. (Can you show the reference? Thanks.) After all, in Cantonese we don't use 块/塊 to mean dollar (at least spoken). Yes in Chinese we write 一塊錢 but it is seldom spoken out that way in Cantonese. We say 一「蚊」.

Comment: @leo4jc 量詞。塊（指較小的）

一窟布。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BC%97), the possible meanings of 弗 are:

- as negation (as in, 不 and 否 for "no")
- gust of wind
- writing brush

There is no mention if it can mean dollar.

---

On the other hand, in Japanese, the possible meanings are:

- fluorine
- the dollar sign ($)

The reason of the dollar sign is because of the similarity of the sign itself (弗 vs $).

> Repurposed for its visual similarity to the dollar symbol $. This reading is ultimately a borrowing from Dutch dollar.

Comment: Wow! +1 It's amazing how Japanese language re-purposes Chinese characters so easily. With even more similarities to 弗 is the [Portuguese Cifrão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifr%C3%A3o) which has 2 vertical slashes. It was used before the Euro currency.

Comment: @Armfoot sometimes dollar sign is also written with 2 vertical slashes. The rendition on this page really depends on what font your browser chooses. But you're right, the Cifrao is more similar since it's always written with 2 slashes.

Answer (score 2):

Chinese usually use 美元 as dollar. For example, 14 dollar is 14 美元. I never saw Chinese use 弗 refered to dollar.

Answer (score -1):

Someone will use 刀 for dollar because of the pronunciation, but 弗 is not used as $.

Comment: Yes. That's true. Many of my friends use 刀 as well. They even use "人刀" for RMB.